# AADSTS7000012: The grant was obtained for a different tenant

Tags: java, azure-ad-msal

When I try to connect with Microsoft graph with a personal acount, I get this error message: AADSTS7000012: The grant was obtained for a different tenant.

I am following this tutorial https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapp/tree/master/msal-java-webapp-sample, and it works fine with professional account.

Also I don't find any documentation on this AADSTS7000012 error code!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, for my case i had to use this url : https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/

For organizations only the url must be : https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations

And only for the same tenant of the organization : [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenantId%7D)